# Different results of feature importance using mlr and randomForest packages

Tags: r, random-forest, mlr

So I want to perform feature selection for my random forest model. First I used mlr then randomForest package just to checked everything and the results of feature importance differ.

```r
#MLR
#DEFINE A TASK
HP48_task <- makeClassifTask(data=df_24cech_zap_omit, target='HP48')

#Feature filtering
fv = generateFilterValuesData(HP48_task, method=c('randomForest_importance'))
fv$data

#randomForest
model_first <- randomForest(HP48~., data=df_24cech_zap_omit ,importance = T)
importance(model_first, class='HP48')
```

```r
> head(fv$data)
                name    type randomForest_importance 
1           PLEC_ALL  factor                6.284084
2           wiek2015 numeric                6.779634
3         wiek6_2015  factor                5.042052
4        L_OSOB_2015 numeric                3.113163 
5 KLASA_MIEJSCOWOSCI  factor                6.987793
6               HC11  factor                5.506360

> head(importance(model_first, class='HP48'))
                         NIE        TAK MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
PLEC_ALL            6.118796 -0.6763398             5.403122         14.81937
wiek2015           10.191208  0.4670294             9.553786         80.99328
wiek6_2015          5.367055  0.1594754             5.090515         37.88534
L_OSOB_2015         4.916890 -1.1206233             3.913224         51.55660
KLASA_MIEJSCOWOSCI 10.066962 -1.4121966             9.147862         59.66335
HC11                5.929320  1.5730634             6.191208         24.77438
```

Is it normal or I make some mistakes in code? Which importance measure should I trust?

Comment: This could be because of different random initializations for the random forest. Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Unfortunately I'm working on a very big datasets (about 85000 observations) and this is part of my thesis so it's unpossible to provide complete example. I was thinking that this problem could be because of different random initializations but the order of feature can differ so significantly? https://imgur.com/a/MkxZA9v

Comment: Can't say without the data. You could try setting the random seed. Unfortunately there's not a lot we can do without a reproducible example. You could try with a smaller dataset and see if you run into the same issue.

Comment: No need for your dataset, just use a toy dataset from mlr. And try if setting a seed helps.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the seed does not yield the same results. There has to be something going on in `generateFilterValuesData()` that uses the RNG because I checked the source of the randomForest_importance method and it does exactly the same as in the example. I suggest using bootstrapping or similar to obtain error bounds for the importance values.